# replace inner join with select from, perhaps?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to understand and modify an SQL query used by an input field to do a smart search.

The original code is here:

```
((`clients` INNER JOIN `addresstorecord` ON `clients`.`uuid` = 
   `addresstorecord`.`recordid` AND `addresstorecord`.
   `tabledefid`='tbld:6d290174-8b73-e199-fe6c-bcf3d4b61083' AND
    addresstorecord.primary='1') INNER JOIN 
  `addresses` ON  `addresstorecord`.`addressid` = `addresses`.`uuid`)
```

I do not actually need an inner join, as all my information is already in one table.

In that case, could I theoretically just replace the inner join query with my table name? Or would I have to actually do a select from statement?

Comment: Wouldn't trying it be quicker than asking here?

Comment: well, yes, except it doesn't work and I am wondering if this is why, or if it theoretically should work. If it should work, then something else is likely the problem.

Comment: The snippet you have posted refers to 3 tables: `addresses`, `addresstorecord`, `clients`.  As Bill Karwin has said, the purpose of the joins could be to restrict the final result set. They could also be necessary if there is required data in these tables.  However, you don't appear to have posted the full query, which makes it difficult to understand exactly what it is supposed to do. You also haven't said why it is that you want to change it, or what result you want to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query can use a join to restrict rows in the result set, not only to get additional columns to show.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (col1) VALUES (10), (20), (30);
INSERT INTO tableB (col1) VALUES (20);

SELECT tableA.col1 FROM tableA;
```

Returns three rows: 10, 20, and 30.

```
SELECT tableA.col1 FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.col1 = tableB.col1;
```

Returns one row: 20.

So in your example, the join means the query returns only those `clients` who have a matching row in `addresses`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that

I don´t need that at all, as all my data is only in one table.

Since the query in my example seems to be a parameter to a query rather than a query itself, would replacing it with just the name of the table containing my data be sufficient?

Comment: I can't answer that without seeing the query and a description of the desired result of the query.  You have supplied neither.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the Joins, you will output all the rows in clients table. If that is what you want, you can remove the joins, but i don think so. The joins are actually filtering your output to give only the clients rows where `clients.uuid = addresstorecord.recordid` and so on. I think all the data you want to see in output is in the clients table but the data you need to filter is not so you need the joins.